# Unable to parse JSON returning NULL

Tags: json, jq

I have a small script that reads certain information from JSON and prints it.Running this script throws this error:

jq: error (at :1): Cannot iterate over null (null)

Can someone please let me know what maybe the cause of this returning null:

```
test5(){
local file="test.json"
    while read rule; do
    local priority
    local access
    local direction
    local name
    local src
    local protocol
    local ports
    local cidr
    local nsg
    
    
    name=$(jq --raw-output '.name' <<< ${rule})
    direction=$(jq --raw-output '.direction' <<< ${rule})
    protocol=$(jq --raw-output '.protocol' <<< ${rule})
    priority=$(jq --raw-output '.priority' <<< ${rule})
    access=$(jq --raw-output '.access' <<< ${rule})
    nsg=$(jq --raw-output '.nsg' <<< ${rule})
    src=$(jq --raw-output '.source | join(" ")' <<< ${rule})
    cidr=$(jq --raw-output '.cidr | join(" ")' <<< ${rule})
    ports=$(jq --raw-output '.ports | join(" ")' <<< ${rule})
    
    
    
    echo "${priority}"
    done < <(cat ${file} | jq -rc '.[]')
    
}
```

JSON:

```
[ {
  "name" : "AllowHttpsInBound",
  "direction" : "Inbound",
  "protocol" : "tcp",
  "priority" : 1000,
  "access" : "Allow",
  "nsgName" : "something",
  "sourceAddressPrefixes" : [ "something" ],
  "destinationAddressPrefixes" : [ "*" ],
  "destinationPortRanges" : [ "9443" ]
}, {
  "name" : "AllowInBound",
  "direction" : "Inbound",
  "protocol" : "*",
  "priority" : 1100,
  "access" : "Allow",
  "nsgName" : "SOMETHING",
  "sourceAddressPrefixes" : [ "something" ],
  "destinationAddressPrefixes" : [ "*" ],
  "destinationPortRanges" : [ "*" ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the objects in your json file does not contain the keys `source`, `cidr`, `ports`.
Accessing non existing keys produces `null`. The filter `join(" ")` then fails.

A possible solution to fix this would be to provide an empty array as a default wherever it may be missing in the source:

```
src=$(jq --raw-output '.source? // [] | join(" ")' <<< ${rule})
cidr=$(jq --raw-output '.cidr? // [] | join(" ")' <<< ${rule})
ports=$(jq --raw-output '.ports? // [] | join(" ")' <<< ${rule})
```

Comment: Thanks. It never occurred to me that I can also change variable names.